# Entity Framework - Parent Child

Tags: .net, entity

I have a Parent Child entity that represents a folder. Each Folder has a ParentFolderID foreign Key.
I need to write a method that gets a folder name and returns the root Folder (a folder with ParentFolder - NULL) that leads to the relevent folders. I don't want to see other Child Folders of a specific Folder.
How can i do it?

For example-
i have a folder tree-
Michael-->A  &  A1-->B-->C-->D

and i search for the folder with Name C. 
So i need the method to return :
Michael-->A1-->B-->C
('A' Folder is not seen since it doesn't lead to the 'C' Folder)

Comment: Why don't you just climb up the tree iteratively? Something like `while(currentNode.Parent != NULL) currentNode = currentNode.Parent;`

Comment: because for this i need to get all folders existing in the DB. I want the query to be run on DB will be as small as possible (only the relevant folders will be retrieved)

Comment: No, you don't need to get all folders. If you query a folder's parent, EF will generate a query that returns exactly this folder. Therefore, you only have to retrieve the parents from the database.

Comment: Well, I solved my problem. I wrote a recursive method that receives a folder , and checks if it is a root folder. if yes- return it. If no- get it's parent folder (including it's parent folder) from DB and call again to method.